# Eloquent Relationship with Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5

I have the following Models with corresponding tables:

User (users), UserProfile (user_profiles), Review (reviews)

**Schema**

```
table: users

user_id (primary key)
first_name
last_name

table: user_profiles
user_id (foreign key)
country
phone

table: reviews
reviewer_id (the user who posted the review)
user_id (foreign key)
body
```

I query the database with the following:

```
$user = User::with('profile', 'review')->find(Auth::User()->user_id);
```

**Part of User Model**

```
public function profile(){
    return $this->hasOne(UserProfile::class, 'user_id');
}    

public function review(){
    return $this->hasOne(Review::class, 'user_id');
}
```

**Part of UserProfile Model**

```
 public function users() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
 }
```

**Part of Review Model**

```
 public function users() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
 }
```

How can I access the details of the `reviewer` using the `reviewer_id` from the `users` table

Comment: Your relationship is not a many to many, it's a many to one. User should `$this->haveMany()` and UserProfile should `$this->belongsTo()`

Comment: Your question is confusing as to what is the difference between `reviewer_id` and `user_id`. It looks like they're the same thing.

Comment: The `reviewer_id` is actually holding a `user_id` data but for a user who writes a review

Comment: In the Review Model, you should have one method for `user()` with belongsTo User with `user_id` and one method for `reviewer()` with belongsTo User with `reviewer_id`. Then, from your $user variable do `$user->review->reviewer` should give you the user through `reviewer_id`

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu Thanks, worked as wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a sunup of what was discussed in this question, I think the major concern of OP was regarding a table that have 2 foreign keys with the same table. Both `user_id` and `reviewer_id` are foreign keys linked to the `users` table.

One important thing to understand about Laravel relationships is that the relationship name is not hard bound, it can be anything as long as it makes sense to you. The related object will be available in the **ATTRIBUTE** with the exact name of the **METHOD**.

```
class User extends Model {

     public function review() {
         return $this->hasOne(Review::class);
     }
}
```

A user's review will be available at `User::find(1)->review;`.

```
class Review extends Model {

     public function owner() {
         return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
     }

     public function reviewer() {
         return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'reviewer_id');    
     }
}
```

From a review, you will be able to access both users:

```
Review::find(1)->owner; // This is the relationship with user_id column
Review::find(1)->reviewer; // This is the relationship with reviewer_id column
```